# Using scopes in activerecord queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope, where-clause

I have a scope in user.rb

```
scope :active, -some logic here-
```

How can I use this a `where` query, something like

```
User.where("users.active is not nil")
```

Is there a way to use scopes in a `where` clause?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is. Just like this:

```
User.where("users.active is not nil").active
```

Comment: why did you add the second `active` scoping?

Comment: What do you mean second? If I understand you correctly, you want to use your "active" scope with this where query and this is how you can do it.

Comment: I want to get all users who are active. the active scope pulls some records from the db. if it is null, then the user isn't active. Why isn't `User.where("users.active is not nil")` suffice?

Comment: Then if you scope logic doing the same as your where query, there's no need to use the latest. Just do it like this:
     User.active